# How to drop terms from a mixed model formula

Tags: regex, r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I have a rather specific regular expressions problem that is causing me some grief. I have removed one or more fixed effects from a mixed model (either `lme` or `lme4`), and wish to remove the corresponding random slope(s). However, depending on the random structure, this may leave behind unnecessary `+` symbols or, worse, leave nothing preceding the `|`.

Take a list of random effects formulae from `lme` and `lme4` obtained using `lme.model$call$random` and `findbars(formula(lme4.model))` respectively:

```
   random.structures = list(
  "~ b | random1",
  "(b | random1)",
  "~ b + x1 | random1",
  "(b + x1 | random1)",
  "~ x1 + b| random1",
  "(x1 + b| random1)",
  "~ b + x1 + c | random1",
  "(b+ x1 + c | random1)",
  "~b + x1 + x2 | random1",
  "(b + x1 + x2 | random1)",
  "~ x1 + x2 + b | random1",
  "(x1 + x2 + b | random1)"
)
```

I have removed the variables `b` and `c` from the fixed effects formula using `dropterms`. Since they no longer exist as fixed effects, their random slopes should not be allowed to vary.

`b` and `c` can be removed from the random formulae above using the following line:

```
random.structures = lapply(random.structures, function(i) gsub("b|c", "", i))
```

Now, I wish to remove all leftover `+` symbols, i.e., those that do not link variables.

Then, in the event there is a blank space between `~` or `(` and `|`, I wish to insert a `1`.

The desired output is

```
random.structures2 = list(
  "~ 1 | random1",
  "(1 | random1)",
  "~ x1 | random1",
  "(x1 | random1)",
  "~ x1 | random1",
  "(x1 | random1)",
  "~ x1 | random1",
  "(x1 | random1)",
  "~ x1 + x2 | random1",
  "(x1 + x2 | random1)",
  "~ x1 + x2 | random1",
  "(x1 + x2 | random1)"
)
```

I have fiddled with `gsub` but just can't seem to get it right. For instance, this works:

```
gsub("(.*)\\+\\ |(.*)\\+(\\|)", "\\1", random.structures[[3]])
# Accounting for space or lack of space between + and |
```

But not for this:

```
gsub("(.*)\\+\\ |(.*)\\+(\\|)", "\\1", random.structures[[7]])
```

Alternately, if there is a preexisting function like `dropterms` for random structures, I'm all in!

Similarly, I can't reliable insert a `1` in the blank space inbetween `~ |` or `( |`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to solve this regular expressions? If you are working with formulas, there are other functions for manipulating formulas that won't result in invalid syntax. If you want to remove a variable, try `update(y~a+b, ~.-b)`

Comment: Will this work for mixed models, particularly those in the `lme4` package where `update` works on the whole formula (fixed and random effects)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example of what you are *actually* trying to accomplish. Provide input formulas, the variables you want to remove, and desired output.

Comment: I have updated the question demonstrating with the entire `random.structures` list should look like, in addition to the two examples I provided.

Comment: But your example still starts with an arbitrary string (invalid formula).What did the formulas look like before you removed the variable? How did you attempt to remove the variable? There are probably better ways to remove the variable in the first place. It's better to fix the problem at the source rather than cleaning up downstream.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail that perhaps will elucidate my motivations more clearly. Let me know if you need further detail!

Comment: Ah well, I've given up on answering this, but (1) consider using a vector; there's no need for a list here and (2) perhaps you can construct the formulas you want instead of parsing them after the fact.

Comment: Piecing together the random formula instead of replacing existing variables proved to be the most effective method -- thanks for the suggestion @Frank

Comment: @jslefche Glad to hear you found a solution. If you have time and inclination, you could write your approach up as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Half the items in your starting list are proper formulas (the ones with the "~"). I'm not sure what you are doing with the terms in the parenthesis. But for the formulas, you can use the `Formula` package for better support for dropping terms with conditioning terms.

Here I'll subset to the proper formulas and convert to `Formula` objects.

```
library(Formula)
rx <- lapply(random.structures[grep("~", random.structures)],
    function(x) Formula(as.formula(x)))
```

We can quickly peak at the results with

```
sapply(rx, deparse)

# [1] "~b | random1"
# [2] "~b + x1 | random1"
# [3] "~x1 + b | random1"
# [4] "~b + x1 + c | random1"
# [5] "~b + x1 + x2 | random1"
# [6] "~x1 + x2 + b | random1"
```

Now we can remove `b` and `c` from all of these with

```
nx <- lapply(x, function(x) update(x, ~.-b-c))
```

and view the results with

```
sapply(nx, deparse)

# [1] "~1 | random1" 
# [2] "~x1 | random1"
# [3] "~x1 | random1"
# [4] "~x1 | random1"
# [5] "~x1 + x2 | random1"
# [6] "~x1 + x2 | random1"
```

You should have no problem using these where ever you would use regular formulas.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting approach and should work for `lme` where the random effects formula is stored separately -- thanks!. I wasn't aware `Formula` would preserve the bars. But unfortunately it will not work with the syntax from `lmer` -- it will not remove or replace the random slope, e.g.: 

`x = "y ~ x2 + (x2 | random1)";
x = Formula(as.formula(x));
update(x, ~.-x2)`